# Differences of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I struggled proving the following propositions, I'd be glad if anyone could help:
$$ (X \cup Y)\setminus(Y \cap Z)=(X\setminus Y)\cup(Y \setminus Z)\\(X \cup Y)\setminus (Y\cup Z) = X \setminus (Y \cup Z)$$

I shall mention my approach was working cases, along the lines of "if x $\in X $, then...". Though I couldn't work these specific two arguments.

EDIT: I'm asking for the proof. I already validated the arguments using Venn diagrams. If someone can post a proof using algebra of sets I'd apprieciate it.

Comment: When you write $/$ do you mean $\setminus$?

Comment: I do, it ruined my latex code.

Comment: Use `\setminus` to produce $\setminus$.

Comment: I figured, wasn't aware of that tag. Sorry.

Comment: Have you drawn Venn diagrams for the four expressions so you can convince yourself that the identities hold?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I already did, but I just didn't manage to show it algebric-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, $A=B ⇔ ((\forall x \in A ⇒x\in B) \land (\forall x \in B⇒x\in A))$. Looking at the definition you can notice that the right hand side is nothing but two two directions of subset. 
Therefore, suppose $A, B$ are two sets, then to show $A=B$ it suffices to show $(A \subseteq B) \land (B \subseteq A)$.

Now, In order to show $A\subseteq B$. Assume an arbitrary $x \in  A$, then show $x\in B$.

I will show one direction of subset for the first one, the other is quite similar I hope you will be able to do it.

Suppose $x\in ((X\cup Y)\setminus(Y\cap Z))$. Then, $(x\in X \lor x\in Y) \land (x\notin Y\land x\notin Z)$

As you can see, the above atomics follow from the definition of union, intersection, and difference.
Since $(x\in X \lor x\in Y) \land (x\notin Y\land x\notin Z)$, then $((x\in X\land x\notin Y)\lor (x\in Y\land x\notin Z))$. I got these by De Morgan distribution.

Finally, Translate the definitions into the respective symbol:$((x\in X\land x\notin Y)\lor (x\in Y\land x\notin Z))≡x\in ((X\setminus Y)\lor (Y\setminus Z))$

Which implies: $x\in ((X\setminus Y)\cup(Y\setminus Z))$.

Therefore, $((X\cup Y)\setminus (Y\cap Z))\subseteq ((X\setminus Y)\cup(Y\setminus Z))$

---

### **Here is another proof with additional explanations**

Show that $(X\cup Y)\setminus (Y\cap Z)=(X\setminus Y)\cup(Y\setminus Z)$

Suppose: $$x\in (X\cup Y)\land x\notin (Y\cup Z)$$
Above supposition follows from the definition of difference.$$x\in(X\cup Y)\rightarrow (x\in X \lor x\in Y)\land x\notin (Y\cap Z)\rightarrow (x\notin Y \lor x\notin Z)$$$$Supp. x\in X \land x\notin Y\rightarrow x\in(X\setminus Y)(a)$$$$Supp.x\in X\land x\notin Z\rightarrow x\in(X\setminus Z)(b)$$$$Supp.x\in Y\land x\notin Y\rightarrow \bot$$$$Supp.x\in Y \land x\notin Z \rightarrow x\in (Y\setminus Z)(c)$$

Therefore, from **a** and **c**, $$x\in (X\setminus Y)\cup (Y\cap Z)\rightarrow (X\cup Y)\setminus (Y\cap Z)\subseteq(X\setminus Y)\cup(Y\setminus Z)$$

The other direction of subset is very similar to this one, hopefully you can do it.

Comment: I'm aware of how one shall prove the equality of two sets. But I didn't manange to show that $ L.H.S \in R.H.S $ or the vice versa.

Comment: @user-2147482321 I added one direction subset proof for one of it and the rest hopefully you can do yourself.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but as far as I am concered, if $ x \notin ( Y \cap Z), it implies $ x \notin Y \cup x \notin Z. While you stated x not in both. So how you developed (Y and Z)' to Y' and Z' instead of or between them.

Comment: @ILoveMath Let's go back to the definition of an intersection: $A\cap B=\{x|x\in A \land x\in B\}$. I just implemented the definition of an intersection. As a general hint, always keep the set-builder definitions in mind. More than 80 percent of the time it will solve half of the problem.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for the correction, it is fixed now.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help. As for your answer, I know the definition of intersection but it seems odd to me what you did ther because:   $ x not in (X and Y), hence x doesn't belong to X, Y, or both. But you assumed he doesn't belong to both. It's bascially one of De Morgan's law what I'm saying. (X \cap Y)' = X' \cup Y'. Yet you developed it to X' cap Y'.

Comment: @ILoveMath You are welcome. Notice, I did not use De Morgan for the step you are referring to. I only used De Morgan in the very last part. Also, don't think of $x\notin (A \cap B)$ as $x \notin (A \land B)$. Intersection and Union are set-theoretic concepts, and they have set theoretic definitions. They are not necessarily boolean. Also, If you are concerned that the step I took was invalid when I translated $x \notin (A \cap B)$ to $(x \notin A) \land (x \notin B)$. Then rest assured, the step is nothing but the implication of the definition of $A\cap B$

Comment: Okay, to just to clarify. If I know x doesn't belong to the intersection of two sets I can deduce he doesn't belong to them both? (I know it sounds quite stupid but I insisted I should consider the cases where he doesn't belong to only one of them)

Comment: @ILoveMath Yes. However, if x does not belong to the union of two, then you work cases. I think you were confusing union with intersection.

Comment: Quite odd, logically it seems reasonable to me that if an element doesn't belong to the **union** of two sets, **then it shall not be in both sets**. (Since it requires the element to be in at least one of the sets, and if not - 0). Anyway, thanks for the patience dude.

Comment: @ILoveMath I see what you are saying now. That is, if x is not in the intersection it is not necessary that it is in neither. That is true, I should have stated that. However, regardless of that fact, the initial proof is rigorous it does not depend on it. I have added another proof which follows the pattern you are taught. Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: Yess, that was my point. Thank you! It is clear to me now. Just out of curiosity, how it was valid in your first proof? Or rather, there are times I am allowed to deduce it's not in the intersection? I figure given extra information, though I didn't find anything relevant to that.

Comment: @ILoveMath Notice how we are given that x could be in either in X or Y, but it can not be in the intersection of Y and Z. From that, we can safely say x is not Z if x is in Y. Hence, $x\notin Z$. Also, Notice, if we have an atomic formula $\phi$ we can deduce $\rho \lor  \phi$. using the same logic if you have $x\in \gamma$ you can deduce $x\in (\gamma \cup \delta)$. Using this I got the other formula.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me to get a better grasp at this. Salute.

Comment: @ILoveMath You are welcome, best of luck.